# how to save a certain file name but change the file type in matplotlib.savefig

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-analysis

I have a program to plot data from many files and have a loop to do it and currently have

```
import matplotlib.pyplab as plt
for file in fireplace
    plotting code
    plt.savefig(file.jpg)
```

I want to save the figure with the same text name but as a different extension. Lets say the file is data1.txt, then I make the plot and want the plot to be saves as data1.jpg. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the `os` module:

```
import os
img_filename = os.path.splitext('data1.txt')[0] + '.jpg'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
from os import listdir
file_list = listdir(your_file_path)
for file in file_list:
    # include the code here to read data from file as x and y
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.savefig('outputfolder/%s' %file)
```

Comment: Is it working?? why down vote, without saying anything.

Comment: @jakeowen can you add more information about code to plot the data in file. Sample data contained in file.